# ¿Por qué Confirm de Javascript se repite más de dos veces?

Tags: javascript

tengo una inquietud que espero pueda ser resuelta. Tengo una lista de nombres y al darle clic sobre ellos los envío a un formulario para editarlos o eliminarlos. Cuando el usuario lo va a eliminar uso una función de javascript que contiene un Confirm para preguntarle al usuario si está seguro de eliminar el contacto. Sucede que cada vez que pulso sobre un nombre de la lista y le doy al botón de eliminar, el Confirm va aumentando, es decir, sale dos veces, luego tres y así sucesivamente.

Esta es la función que uso cuando el usuario da clic en el botón:

```
function eliminarAgente(){
    $('#formularioAgente').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(confirm("¿Desea eliminar este Agente?")){
            var user = $('#extension').val();
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: '../scripts/admin/eliminarAgente.php',
                 data: {user:user},
                 success(respuesta){
                       alert("Agente eliminado con éxito");
                       $('#nombre').val('');
                       $('#extension').val('');
                       $('#password').val('');
                       $('#check').html('');
                       listaAgentes();
                 }
            });
        }
    });
```

}

A qué se debe esto? Existe una mejor forma para pedirle confirmación al usuario? Muchas gracias

Comment: revisa [ask] y por favor añade el segmento de código que ayude a que los demás puedan identificar tu problema

Comment: Sin ver el código no podemos ayudarte, pero puestos a adivinar seguro que estás añadiendo un event listener cada vez que pulsas eliminar

Comment: Sí, perdón. Ya he añadido el código que estoy usando :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta separar la asignacion del evento `submit` de la función `eliminarAgente`, algo como esto:

```
$('#formularioAgente').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(confirm("¿Desea eliminar este Agente?")){
        var user = $('#extension').val();
        $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '../scripts/admin/eliminarAgente.php',
             data: {user:user},
             success(respuesta){
                   alert("Agente eliminado con éxito");
                   $('#nombre').val('');
                   $('#extension').val('');
                   $('#password').val('');
                   $('#check').html('');
                   listaAgentes();
             }
        });
    }
}); 

function eliminarAgente(){
    $('#formularioAgente').submit();
}
```

Suerte y espero que funcione. Con esto evitas estar asignando constantemente el evento `onSubmit` a tu formulario, que me parece que es el problema de que se repitan varias veces tu `confirm`

**EDIT**:
Otra posible solución es eliminar el `event handler` de tu formulario antes de añadirle el `submit`, asi no se te van acumulando, quedaria de esta manera:

```
function eliminarAgente(){
    $('#formularioAgente').off('submit').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(confirm("¿Desea eliminar este Agente?")){
            var user = $('#extension').val();
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: '../scripts/admin/eliminarAgente.php',
                 data: {user:user},
                 success(respuesta){
                       alert("Agente eliminado con éxito");
                       $('#nombre').val('');
                       $('#extension').val('');
                       $('#password').val('');
                       $('#check').html('');
                       listaAgentes();
                 }
            });
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo había hecho por medio de la función ya que dicho formulario no existe en el DOM cuando este inicia sino que yo lo añado después

Comment: Edit: probaré la segunda solución a ver que tal va, gracias :)

Comment: Si es asi entonces la segunda es la que debe funcionarte